Not showing output Python Constraint, keeps running
from constraint import *
from constraint import Problem, AllDifferentConstraint
problem = Problem()

customers = ["Freda", "Opal", "Penny", "Sarah", "Vicky"]
locations = ["Brownfield", "Durham", "Iowa Falls", "Los Altos", "Redding"]
brands = ["Dodge", "Fiat", "Hyundai", "Jeep", "Nissan"]
durations = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in range(1, 6):
    problem.addVariable(f"Customer_{i}", customers)
    problem.addVariable(f"Location_{i}", locations)
    problem.addVariable(f"Brand_{i}", brands)
    problem.addVariable(f"Duration_{i}", durations)

for attr in ["Customer", "Location", "Brand", "Duration"]:
    problem.addConstraint(AllDifferentConstraint(), [f"{attr}_{i}" for i in range(1, 6)])

problem.addConstraint(lambda c1, c2, c3, c4: len({c1, c2, c3, c4}) == 4,
                      ["Customer_5", "Location_4", "Location_2", "Brand_2"])
problem.addConstraint(lambda brand, location: brand != "Jeep" or location != "Iowa Falls",
                      ["Brand_3", "Location_3"])
problem.addConstraint(lambda c, d: c != "Penny" or d != 6, ["Customer_4", "Duration_4"])

solutions = problem.getSolutions()
for solution in solutions:
    print(solution)

This is the code. When I try to run the code, the code keeps running and does not show any output or error. I'm not sure why.
I also tried a few simple python constraint problems. It happens the same. It would be of great help if anyone helps me with this issue. Thank you.


You have variables for five customers, each with five possible values
for Location, Brand, and Duration. With these, there are   N^y
permutations per slot, which grows exponentially when constraints are
added.
AllDifferentConstraint() requires that each variable in    the
specified list has a unique value. And it might become computationally heavy because its growing exponentially.Like there would be 5^4 permutations per slot.

Try once below code and let me know if it works,otherwise will try some other way.
I tried below code..took around 3 hours as per my system capacity. and it worked.
!pip install python-constraint  
from constraint import Problem, AllDifferentConstraint

problem = Problem()

customers = ["Freda", "Opal", "Penny", "Sarah", "Vicky"]
locations = ["Brownfield", "Durham", "Iowa Falls", "Los Altos", "Redding"]
brands = ["Dodge", "Fiat", "Hyundai", "Jeep", "Nissan"]
durations = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

 
for i in range(1, 6):
    problem.addVariable(f"Customer_{i}", customers)
    problem.addVariable(f"Location_{i}", locations)
    problem.addVariable(f"Brand_{i}", brands)
    problem.addVariable(f"Duration_{i}", durations)

 
for attr in ["Customer", "Location", "Brand", "Duration"]:
    problem.addConstraint(AllDifferentConstraint(), [f"{attr}_{i}" for i in range(1, 6)])

 
problem.addConstraint(lambda c1, c2, c3, c4: len({c1, c2, c3, c4}) == 4,
                      ["Customer_5", "Location_4", "Location_2", "Brand_2"])
problem.addConstraint(lambda brand, location: brand != "Jeep" or location != "Iowa Falls",
                      ["Brand_3", "Location_3"])
problem.addConstraint(lambda c, d: c != "Penny" or d != 6, ["Customer_4", "Duration_4"])

 
solutions = problem.getSolutions()
if solutions:
    print("Solutions found:")
    for solution in solutions[:5]:  # Displaying the first 5 solutions only
        print(solution)
else:
    print("No solutions found.")


It took me 2 hours, man.

sai,does it worked

Yeah, man. It worked but it takes a lot of time. Thank you for helping me brother.

Sai,you know it man.. Time varies machine to machine based on configuration. If it worked for you,please mark it as solved,once you get time

So to check accuracy of  the code,i tried with less permutaions and it took 30 sec around.Then I ran above code.This was the testing code---
from constraint import Problem, AllDifferentConstraint

# Basic setup with fewer constraints to check if it finds solutions quickly
problem = Problem()
customers = ["Freda", "Opal", "Penny", "Sarah", "Vicky"]


for i in range(1, 6):
    problem.addVariable(f"Customer_{i}", customers)


problem.addConstraint(AllDifferentConstraint(), [f"Customer_{i}" for i in range(1, 6)])


solutions = problem.getSolutions()


for solution in solutions:
    print(solution)



Thanks for letting me know, man. I will try this.
